# "Go back" button issue in google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css-animations, browser-cache, back-button

I have a bit of a head scratcher here. My project has a main page in which some transitions happen and some buttons appear. Clicking those buttons allow you to navigate the site. So far so good. On those lets say "secondary" pages I have a series of "back" buttons that take you back to the main page with the following link:

```
<a href="javascript:javascript:history.go(-1)"><p class="backContact">BACK</p></a>
```

Now, this is where it gets specific. When I return on to the main page, I want to return to the main page that's "cached" so basically the main page AFTER the said animations and buttons appear, not back to the page as if I just had come on the website for the first time. Same for when you hit the back arrow on the browser itself.

The code I just posted with the link was doing just that and it works fine in safari and firefox. BUT in chrome the behaviour is different and when the back button is clicked it goes back to the main page before all the animations happen which is really annoying as I just want them to play the first time round else they become tiresome.

Is there anyway to force chrome to come back to the "cached" previous page? Many thanks

Comment: Add an attribute to the url for the "back to front page" link, like `&cached` and check for that attribute in the JS running the animations? If it's there, don't run them?

Comment: this sounds like what i need. I am fairly new, could you explain it a bit more, maybe in an answer? that would help me a lot tx

Comment: the animations are both js and css though

Comment: Then it won't work. At least not as easy.

Comment: ok. some are js though but I am not sure what you mean by &cached could you give me an example?

Comment: I'm on my phone right now, but if you don't get any better solutions, I will write up something later.